# How to Create a View Multiple times with Distinct Controller Instances?

Tags: javascript, sapui5

I'm working on a dashboard with multiple tiles. Every tile is an XML view. At first, every tile view was supposed to be created once, but due to some new requirements, the user should be able to add the same tile multiple times with different configurations.

To achieve this, I simply tried to create a view like this:

```
sap.ui.xmlview({
  viewName: "com.sap.tiles." + selectedTile + "." + selectedTile
});
```

The tile shows up correctly, but it seems like it's using the exact same controller as the already existing tile of the same type. Every variable is already set in the controller. Is it possible to instantiate a new controller?

I've read that using the same view multiple times in one window (with different controller instances) is not possible and components or fragments should be used instead. Is that true, or am I doing something wrong?

Final edit:

I've solved my problem. It was a problem very specific to my code, which lead to a wrong function call. Boghyon Hoffmanns answer helped me find the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The tile shows up correctly, but it seems like it's using the exact same controller as the already existing tile of the same type. Every variable is already set in the controller.

You probably declared the variables in the closure outside of the module definition.

```js
sap.ui.define([
  "sap/ui/core/mvc/Controller",
  // ...
], function(Controller /*, ...*/){
  "use strict";
  var something; // Visible to all Controller instances of the same name

  return Controller.extend("com.sap.tiles...", {
    onInit: function() {
      something = 1; // Applies to all Controller instances of the same name
      this.something = 0; // Applies to this instance only
    },

  });
});
```

Creating the same view multiple times does **not** fetch the corresponding Controller multiple times (since the module has been already defined), but it **does** instantiate the module (Controller) every time when the view is created.

Comment: I've solved the problem thanks to you. It was a very specific coding issue, which lead to the onAfterRendering function being called for each of my controller instances except the new one.

Comment: @ClFi335114 I see. :) I was about to delete my answer but good to know that it was somehow helpful after all.